# Shorthand if/else statement error from missing closing tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use `{props.dollarsInputGroup ? <InputGroup><InputGroup.Addon>$</InputGroup.Addon> : ''}` the statement doesn't work because there is no close tag for `<InputGroup>`. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

```
<FormGroup>
  {props.dollarsInputGroup ? <InputGroup><InputGroup.Addon>$</InputGroup.Addon> : ''}
  <Input />
  {props.dollarsInputGroup ? </InputGroup> : ''}
  {props.error ? <HelpBlock>{props.error}</HelpBlock> : '' }
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: Just add the closing tag?

Comment: The closing tag needs to be after the input field so I can't 'add' it in. It is a separate if/else statement.

Comment: @bp123 Please show us all the code you're dealing with

Comment: `I would like to combine two shorthand if/else statement` - and yet, you show only one such "statement" in the code you want help with ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I've removed `I would like to combine two shorthand if/else statement` as it isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: yet, it seems to be, because you say `It is a separate if/else statement`

Comment: What is this stuff? JSX? Some arbitrary templating language?

Comment: It's JSX. Who down voted? This is a relevant question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to either repeat the `<FormControl />`, or define it once as a variable and use it twice (possibly with a function). For example:

```
var formControl = <FormControl />;
return <FormGroup>
    {props.dollarsInputGroup ? <InputGroup><InputGroup.Addon>$</InputGroup.Addon>{formControl}</InputGroup> : formControl}
    {props.error ? <HelpBlock>{props.error}</HelpBlock> : null}
</FormGroup>;
```

Or… (though I think this is much less readable)

```
<FormGroup>
    {(props.dollarsInputGroup ? ((fc) => <InputGroup><InputGroup.Addon>$</InputGroup.Addon>{fc}</InputGroup>) : ((fc) => fc))(<FormControl />)}
    {props.error ? <HelpBlock>{props.error}</HelpBlock> : null}
</FormGroup>
```

Though you could use a definition elsewhere to help it a bit:

```
function maybeWrapWithDollars(wrapWithDollars, wrappedControl) {
    if(wrapWithDollars) {
        return <InputGroup><InputGroup.Addon>$</InputGroup.Addon>{wrappedControl}</InputGroup>;
    }else{
        return wrappedControl;
    }
}
// …
<FormGroup>
    {maybeWrapWithDollars(props.dollarsInputGroup, <FormControl />)}
    {props.error ? <HelpBlock>{props.error}</HelpBlock> : null}
</FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the conditions:

```
<FormGroup>
  {props.dollarsInputGroup ? <InputGroup><InputGroup.Addon>$</InputGroup.Addon><Input /></InputGroup> : <Input />}
  {props.error ? <HelpBlock>{props.error}</HelpBlock> : '' }
</FormGroup>
```